# Javascript; valid input based on a range of numbers

Tags: javascript, validation, floating-point

I need to validate a user input for a GPA calculator based on the following criteria:

- Is a number
- Is an integer value between 3 and 7, or 1.5 floating point value.

So far I have tried the following:

```
var gradeInputMessage = "Please enter your  grade for course " +userInput;
var gradeInput = "";

gradeInput = prompt(gradeInputMessage);

while (
  isNaN(gradeInput) || //grade input is a number
      gradeInput <3 || gradeInput >7
)
{
alert ("invalid Course Grade. Please try again");
gradeInput = prompt(gradeInputMessage);
}
```

This seems to work fine for the numbers 3,4,5,6,7, but I have no idea how to include 1.5

Please excuse any ignorance on my behalf, this is a university course that I have to complete, and I have never done any form of programming, nor do I do any for work.

Appreciate any help/feedback.

Cheers,
Mitchell

Comment: just add `|| gradeInput === 1.5`

Comment: Maybe it's time to use some `regex`?

Comment: you could use an if statement separately just before the while to check "if(gradeInput == 1.5)". do you intend to return some data or do you have some code below the while loop?

Comment: @Hamms— `===` won't work, the value returned by *prompt* is a string. ;-)

Comment: ah, true! In that case, `<3` and `>7` are also going to work unexpectedly, and OP is going to want to throw in a `gradeInput = Number(gradeInput)` somewhere

Answer (score 2):

Probably easier to just check for the things that you want, then `not` them.

Also added a `null` checker so people can hit cancel to exit out of the prompt loop.

And I convert the string into a number by putting `+` in front of `gradeInput`

```js
var gradeInputMessage = "Please enter your  grade for course ";

var gradeInput = prompt(gradeInputMessage);

while (
  gradeInput !== null &&
  (
  isNaN(gradeInput) || //grade input is a number
      !((+gradeInput >=3 && +gradeInput <=7) || +gradeInput === 1.5)
  )
)
{
alert ("invalid Course Grade. Please try again");
gradeInput = prompt(gradeInputMessage);
}
```

Comment: as @RobG pointed out, you'll want to make sure to convert the result of `prompt` to a number before check it

Comment: @Hamms ah, yes, I added `Number` to the bottom, but forgot the top, I could also just do with soft checking :\

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a web app?

html 5 with `type="number"` input can valid the number for you.

I'm using jQuery here but it can be done in pure js easily. also `validGpa.indexOf(gpa)` this is pure js (`.indexOf()`)

my example here use an `Array` to save all valid `GPA`, if any input match then print msg `xx is valid`. If not matching, say `'Sorry ...'`

```js
var validGpa = ['3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '1.5'];
$('#inputgpa').on('change', function() {
  var gpa = $(this).val();
  if (validGpa.indexOf(gpa) > -1) {
    $('#validation').text(gpa + ' is Valid!');
  } else {
    $('#validation').text('Sorry! ->' + gpa + '<- is not a valid GPA...');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Enter your GPA now:<span><br>
<input id="inputgpa" type="number" /><br>
<span id="validation"></span>
```